# Can a ClickOnce application return a value to the page that loaded it?

Tags: browser, parameters, clickonce

I have an online ClickOnce application that launches from a web page. After the application is closed, I would like the user to return to that page with some results passed from the application. Is this possible?

Right now the only solution I have is for the application to upload the results to my server, and have javascript on the launching webpage to poll the server every 15 seconds as it waits for results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible to pass information directly back to the client browser from the ClickOnce installed application.

Your intuition is correct that you should have your application upload results to the server (presumably with the help of WCF) for subsequent processing and display via your polling page.

I'll also add, that in terms of your web application linking to data from the ClickOnce application you will need to come up with a common token between the web application and the ClickOnce application. Perhaps via a customised activation URL link that uses a common GUID generated for the client (e.g. http://myserver.com/myapplication.application?id=18c40c3d-183c-4c22-8127-37cac3be6492).